# Can I add database to AWS RDS MySQL without creating new instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

Just like a vps/server when I install mysql on it, it can be flexible to add/remove database in one server, but on aws rds mysql can I add database without create a new instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, login with the *master user / password* credentials that you used when creating the instance and then create the database:

```
$ mysql -u{MasterUser} -p{MasterPassword} -hmysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
mysql> CREATE DATABASE new_db;
mysql> CREATE USER ...
mysql> GRANT ...;
```

Just like with any other MySQL server.

If you prefer a GUI interface you can use for example **[Adminer](https://adminer.org)** or something like that.

Hope that helps :)